Convert category structure to merge with other df
I have 2 dfs, the first df has transactions that each have a category id, the categories are multi layered and the number of layers varies. The 2. df has the categories. for each category it has the category id and the parent id. I would like to prepare df 2 in such a way that i can merge it with df 1 and then have all the layers of the categories in df1.
DF1:



Transaction ID
Category_id




1
Apples


2
Garlic


3
Car



DF2



category_id
parent_id




Apples
Fruit


Garlic
Veg


Fruit
None


Veg
None


Car
None



Desired Result
Transaction ID | Category_0 | Category_1 |
1 | Apples | Fruit |
...
3 | None | Car
representation of the dfs
I have tried different ways matching the dfs but each time i got to a solution where i have too loop over df1 and then loop over df2 which seems very inefficient.

assuming that df means dataframe, you should include the [dataframe] tag in your post and maybe [pandas] as well if you're using that

Just left join them on category ID see this post for an exhaustive list of their interactions.

This question is similar to: Pandas Merging 101. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Outer Merge will help:
import pandas as pd

file = '/content/20240905_Temp_Table_Analysis.xlsx' #Link to File

ds1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet2') # Table 1
ds2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet3') # Table 2

# Merge Tables
ds_1 = ds1.merge(ds2, how='outer', left_on='Category_id', right_on='category_id')

ds_2 = ds_1.drop('category_id', axis=1, inplace=False)

ds_2.head()



Hi, thank you for the reply. My categories are multi level, so in my result df i would like to have a column for each level, so level_0,level_1,level_2, etc. not sure if your solution works like this.
